# Inserting a String Alphabetically in List in C++

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator

I'm trying to insert a sample vector of string values into a pre-sorted list alphabetically (and without using/writing a sort function). I got part of the code correctly, where a string would be inserted into the list. However, since I am not that familiar with iterators, my if statement is incomplete and the string is continuously pushed afterwards for all values that meet the condition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::list<std::string> update(std::list<std::string>& data, std::vector<std::string> add){
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator add_itr;
   std::list<std::string>::iterator data_itr;

   for (data_itr = data.begin(); data_itr != data.end(); data_itr++){
    for (add_itr = add.begin(); add_itr != add.end(); add_itr++){
       //this condition is incomplete 
       if (*add_itr < *data_itr)
          data.insert(data_itr, *add_itr);

      }
   }

   return data;
}

void print(const std::string &label, const std::list<std::string> &data) {
  std::cout << label;
  for (std::list<std::string>::const_iterator itr = data.begin();
       itr != data.end(); itr++) {
    std::cout << " " << *itr;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main() {

  std::list<std::string> data;
  data.push_back("antelope");
  data.push_back("catfish");
  data.push_back("giraffe");
  data.push_back("llama");
  data.push_back("jellyfish");
  data.push_back("whale_shark");
  data.push_back("zebra");

  std::vector<std::string> add;
  add.push_back("tiger");
  add.push_back("llama");
  add.push_back("elephant");

  print ("before:",data);
  update(data,add);
  print ("after: ",data);

}
```

I was thinking that the other condition for the if statement should be `&& *add_itr > *`(the data string in the previous position) but I'm not sure how to correctly iterate through the list iterators and write this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Learn to use [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or `std::upper_bound` instead of writing loops.  That's the purpose of these algorithms, and that is to tell you where an item would be placed in a sorted container.  If not that, then learn what those functions do.  Note that your implementation is highly inefficient -- if you want to put an item in a sorted container, then find the position using binary search techniques, not iterating one item at a time through the container.

Comment: I'd never heard of either of those before, and I'll definitely look into them. I'm just learning iterators now and was trying to figure out how incrementing and decrementing them works for lists vs vectors, and using a very basic program to do so.

Comment: Well, the point is that if you have a container of values that will be sorted when inserting elements, then binary search to find the correct spot to insert the item is on average better than iterating through the whole list.  Doesn't matter if it's an STL container or just a regular array of values.  What if the insertion point is close to the end of the sequence, and you already have, say a million items in the container?  If this is a school project, a good teacher would either mention this to you now or hopefully later.

Comment: I see; how will I do the binary search?

Comment: Go to the `std::lower_bound` link.  It shows an implementation of what a binary search would look like.  Also, a `std::list` is a poor container for this anyway, due to not having direct access to a certain item (need to iterate to the item).  But again, don't be surprised if you're asked at some point to do things this way, and not search one-by-one.  Just giving you a head start.

Comment: Do you have to use `std::list`? If you can use `std::set` instead, it will do sorting for you as you insert

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should start using auto as its much easier to read and follow. So instead of declaring

```
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator add_itr;
```

you can directly use:

```
for (auto add_itr = add.begin(); add_itr != add.end(); add_itr++){
```

Now for solution, you don't need to iterate the list `data`. Just iterate vector and insert the value in the list.

Comment: I think the OP wants the container to be sorted post insertion of the new strings. So, probably a single vector and then a sort that runs on the updated list ?

Comment: Vishaal, I wanted the list to be 'sorted' as the strings are inserted (without using a sort function). Is that not possible?

Comment: Aman, if I just insert the values, how would I know if the string is alphabetically before or after the ones in the list?

Comment: The better solution is to not iterate at all, but to use binary search to find the position.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ iterator are aimed for *generic programming*. It means that you can write a collection processing algorithms once and then use it for arbitrary set of collections as long as they support the *iterator concept*.

Here is how you can implement what you need in a generic way.

```
template<typename T, typename K>
void update(T& sortedValues, const K& valuesToAdd) {
    for (auto value : valuesToAdd) {
        auto position = std::lower_bound(sortedValues.begin(), sortedValues.end(), value);
        sortedValues.insert(position, value);
    }
}
```

And of course you can always be more specific about collection types if it's necessary.

Note: in pre-sorted list "jellyfish" should follow before "llama".

Answer (score 0):

It depends much on the underlying data structure, as you are using `std::list` to hold the sorted values, prefer using member functions of `std::list` in this case:

```
void update(std::list<std::string>& data, const std::vector<std::string>& add){
    std::list<std::string> sortedAdd(std::begin(add), std::end(add));
    sortedAdd.sort();
    data.merge(std::move(sortedAdd));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't want to use a sort function and have to use lists for this particular problem, I just created a new iterator that would be one less than the original.

```
for (add_itr = add.begin(); add_itr != add.end(); add_itr++){
     for (data_itr = data.begin(); data_itr != data.end(); data_itr++){
      std::list<std::string>::iterator dnew = data_itr;
      dnew--;
       if ((*add_itr < *data_itr) && (*add_itr > *dnew))
          data.insert(data_itr, *add_itr);
     }
   }
```

I know it's not the most optimal way to do it but it works for this particular problem. Thank you to all that answered - I learned a lot!